# Вывод данных с разных таблиц в RedBeanPHP

Tags: redbeanphp

Мне нужно вывести данные с таблицы posts и с таблицы users. Вот пример: ($user->avatar - не работает в этом примере)

```
                        $posts_all = R::find('posts');
                        
                        foreach ($posts_all as $posts){
                            echo '
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="#0">
                                                <img class="post-avatar" src="../avatar/'.$user->avatar.'">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="#0">'.$posts->login.'</a>
                                            <span>'.$posts->post_time.'</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="post-div-text">
                                    <p>'.$posts->text.'</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>';
                        }
```

Comment: И снова здравствуйте! Надеюсь, на этот раз вы хорошо подумали, прежде чем задать вопрос) Можно попробовать использовать метод `getAll()` для составления произвольного (нужного вам) запроса. Например: `$post_all = R::getAll('SELECT p.*, u.* FROM posts, users WHERE p.user_id = u.id')`. Только надо учитывать, что таблицы должны иметь совпадающий столбец (как `user_id` у `posts` и `id` у `users`)

Comment: А через findOne можно это организовать?

Comment: Не думаю. Все эти методы созданы для относительно простых запросов. К тому же, `findOne()` вернёт 1 строку, а не массив. А вам такое, судя по задаче, не подходит

Comment: Понял, спасибо! Попробую через getAll. Я посмотрел несколько видео на ют и понял о чем вы говорите.